# Group by start and end of the week date

Tags: sql, date, datetime, group-by

I have the below promotion dates:

```
Group: Ambient
Start Date: 03/11/2020   End Date: 09/11/2020
Start Date: 10/11/2020   End Date: 16/11/2020

Group: Chilled
Start Date: 04/11/2020   End Date: 10/11/2020
Start Date: 11/11/2020   End Date: 17/11/2020
etc
```

My data consists of the below columns:
Dates (Daily), Group (Ambient/Chilled), Net Sales, Volume Sold

I want to group the data like the below:

```
Weekly Date, Group, Net Sales, Volume Sold
```

The Weekly date I want the week to start from Tuesday and ending on Monday based on the type of group it is. If the product is chilled I want the week to start from Wednesday and end on Tuesday. I want to do this and include a historical view to compare previous weeks to promotional weeks Example

```
        Week Date     Group      Net Sales    Volume
Row 1 - 27/10/2020    Ambient    £900         30
Row 2 - 03/11/2020    Ambient    £1000        50

Row 3 - 04/11/2020    Chilled    £2000        40
Row 4 - 11/11/2020    Chilled    £1000        30
```

What is the SQL query for changing the week dates?

Answer (score 0):

There might be other ways to do this, but I would it first creating some functions that return me the DOW (Day Of Week) as I wanted (for Tuesday 0, ... Monday 6) and then another function FDOW (First Day Of Week) that use DOW. ie:

```
-- Tuesday = 0...Monday = 6
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DOW]
(
    @date DATETIME
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    RETURN (@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(dw, @date) - 1 - 2) % 7;
END;

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FDOW]
(
    @date DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN DATEADD(d, -dbo.DOW(@date), CAST(@date AS DATE));
END;
```

Having such functions it is easy to group on "WeekStart" which is our FDOW function:

```
Select dbo.FDOW(Dates) as WeekOf, [Group], 
   sum([Net Sales]) [Net Sales],
   sum([Volume Sold]) [Volume]
from myTable
group by dbo.FDOW(Dates) as WeekOf, [Group];
```